# PHP Session ID in URL on localhost

Tags: localhost, osx-mountain-lion, php, sessionid

For some reason, my local install of a project I'm working on is adding the PHP session ID to the URLs. This doesn't happen on any other servers. Is there a setting I can change on my end to alter this? I'm using PHP 5.4 on Mac OS 10.8.2

Sample URL: `http://localhost/project/subfolder/index.php/admin/game?PHPSESSID=mhnpc0g2c8rijqpkf8lhpfshh7`

Should be: `http://localhost/project/subfolder/index.php/admin/game`

**Update:** I've checked my PHP.ini file and I have the following settings correct, but I'm still getting the session ID in the URL.

```
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.use_trans_sid = 0
```

Oh, and for good measure I'm restarting Apache after each change to PHP.ini :-)

**2nd Update:** Where else on my mac could an ini file be hiding? Is PEAR messing with this maybe? Thanks all!

Comment: No, not necessarily. Ok, you might have two php.ini files. One in apache/bin other one is in php folder. You may have to change the config of those two to see the effect of change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
session.use_cookies = 1 session.use_only_cookies = 0 session.use_trans_sid = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Check your php.ini file, more specifically the section about session stuff. Make sure the settings are such that it uses cookies and not URLs.

Comment: See also http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-cookies

Answer (score 2):

you should set in your `php.ini` as follows:

```
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.use_trans_sid = 0
```

**EDIT:**

This can be overriden by php itself using `ini_set` function, also in `.htaccess` file or in the description of the apache's virtual host using the `php_flag`.

A good tool to locate the problem is the `grep` utility. Try using it like that:

```
egrep -ir 'php_falg|ini_set' /etc/httpd/
```

to search in the apache's configuration failes and one more time the same command, but pointing to your project (if it's in `.htaccess` file and on the other servers the virual host is configured with `AllowOverride None` the `.htaccess` file wouldn't work there)

```
egrep -ir 'php_falg|ini_set' ~/Sites/ # or in whathever path your site is.
```

Comment: Thanks! It wasn't that, I guess. Could something else be overriding PHP.ini?